# HTML Margin and padding extrange behaviour

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Well, I am working on a webpage. I want a black aside to the left and the content to the right. Here's the simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" >
  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame 
       Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>indexhtml</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Lorena Soledad">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
</head>

<body>

<aside id="information">
    <header>
        <h1>Web Title</h1>
    </header>

    <footer>
        <p>Description</p>
    </footer>
</aside>

<section id="content">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Menu 1</li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
            <li>Menu 4</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <article>
    </article>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the corresponding CSS stylesheet:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; /*Para ocupar todo el ancho y el alto de la pantalla*/
}


section#content {
    background-image: url("img/crossword.png");
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}


aside#information {
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The thing is, I want the body to fill the whole browser. So, as you can see, I used this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

But there are still a few pixels at the top of the browser, just like [this](http://postimg.org/image/8scat6d73/)

So... Searching on the web I found the next code, using the universal selector, and moved the margin and padding properties out of html and body, just like this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And this worked! And I don't know why.
Html tag isn't supposed to be the first tag containing everything?
I mean, why it does not work when I define margins and paddings **in** the html/body tag, but it does work when I define it in the **universal selector**? I don't understand.

I hope somebody will explain this to me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `margin` is caused by your `ul` tag, which is pushing your `section` down.

The `ul` tag has a default of `1em` margin top and bottom, and the universal selector in your second CSS block is removing that.

http://jsfiddle.net/bbr716yh/

Comment: Thank you very much, Matt! I've been inspecting elements with Firefox but it tricked me and I didn't realize. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just use chrome and rightclick that white area, choose inspect elemnt and you should see what it is. Maybe the aside or header element...